# Can't boot Arch Linux after installation with dm-crypt whole system encryption (BIOS)

Tags: arch-linux, dm-crypt, whole-drive-encryption

So I'm installing a new Arch with the document [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#Encrypted_boot_partition_.28GRUB.29) for a whole system encryption.

The first part I get confused is [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#Preparing_the_boot_partition_5) which the document wrote:

> Warning: GRUB does not support LUKS2. Do not use LUKS2 on partitions that GRUB needs to access.

But in the later part of the section, it told me to run the command `cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sda3`. But as I run it it ask for a password but doesn't it said GRUB doesn't support LUKS2?

Later I enter the password, go down through to [grub installing](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#Configuring_the_boot_loader_6) which I run `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` and it said `filaed to connect lvmetad`, but since it's warning I ignored it.

Later I go through the process till the [last part](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#Configuring_fstab_and_crypttab_2) without getting any error.

But then I exit `arch-chroot` and reboot but it can't boot, it skipped to next OS (which is Windows 10 in my case), why? Which part did I get wrong? How to solve it?

P.S. Here is a table of my disk with command `lsblk`

```
NAME                 SIZE     TYPE    MOUNTPOINT
sda                  114.6G   disk    
  sda1               4G       part
  sda2               4G       part    /mnt/boot/efi
  sda3               16G      part    
    cryptboot        16G      crypt   /mnt/boot
  sda4               90.6G    part    
    lvm              90.6G    crypt
      AALEvol-swap   8G       lvm     [SWAP]
      AALEvol-root   82.6G    lvm     /mnt
```

Comment: Did you add an entry for Arch in your grub config as [per the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#Dual-booting)? Post the config.

Comment: And why do you have an ESP (`/boot/efi`) is this is a BIOS install?

Comment: @jasonwryan First the document said it can run on UEFI and second in truly running on UEFI and third I install grub with x86_64-efi

Comment: Of course Grub can work with UEFI: but your question title explicitly mentions BIOS (MBR).

Comment: @jasonwryan I'm just specifying way sine there is many section in the document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a partition on beginning of your Hard Disk Drive, it's size should be between 600 MB and 1GB, and in Linux setup mark that partition as **/boot** partition. **You shouldn't encrypt the boot partition as none of your potentially sensitive data will be written to it.**

If you want to wipe the entire Hard Disk Drive before re-partitioning, i suggest you use **fdisk -l | more** to list all your Hard Disk Drives and all partitions on them, then when you find the drive do 
**dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sd(X)** where X is your HDD letter.

Then create other partitions which will be encrypted: 1./SWAP, 2./ROOT and 3. /HOME (optional).

Comment: I think mine sda1 is use as boot (unencrypted) according to the documentation (/Dev/sdaW) but don't know why it isn't used in the documentation?

Comment: Because people can but don't have to install Linux on /dev/sda1 (first HDD and first partition on it). It can be installed on any HDD and any partition.

Comment: Use **fdisk -l | more** to list all partitions, don't play around with "I think", you must be certain or you'll mess something up -- in computer world everything should be accurate.

Comment: [Here is the partition list](https://1drv.ms/i/s!AifrtKYSrTy6-DFuEf5Ppv4pE4M3)

Comment: But if you look back at the document preparing boot section it said create luks container at sda3 which should be mount at /boot/efi?

Comment: Ok. Here's what you should do: Unless you have any important data on your 114 GB HDD (one from your photo), do **dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda**, that will wipe off all partitions and data from it. Then Create 1 GB partition and assign it as boot, 2nd partition should be SWAP (put it on beginning of HDD where heads have as little movement as possible). Size of SWAP should be **your amount of RAM x1-5 - 2** So if yo have 2 GB RAM, SWAP should be between 3 and 4 GB. Then the rest of SPACE you can use as ROOT and HOME. Also add encryption to all partitions except BOOT partition.

Comment: So let me make sure, first setup `boot` and `swap` partition, then create another partition, use `cryptsetup luksFormat --type luks2 /dev/sda3` to create an volume on it and mount to root. right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73314/discussion-between-fido-x-and-munucial).

Comment: But now the swap partition isn't encrypted? Shouldn't `swap` needs to encrypt due to some data can still be store in `swap`?

Comment: Answered in Chat... this is getting lengthy and i want to follow rules.

Answer (score 2):

GRUB does not (currently) support LUKS2, so /boot cannot be LUKS2 encrypted.

cryptsetup (since version 2.1.0) creates LUKS2 by default, unless otherwise specified by the distro packager. So currently ArchLinux produces LUKS2 containers by default.

https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/blob/master/docs/v2.1.0-ReleaseNotes :

> Cryptsetup 2.1 version uses a new on-disk LUKS2 format as the default LUKS format and increases default LUKS2 header size.
>
> The legacy LUKS (referenced as LUKS1) will be fully supported forever as well as a traditional and fully backward compatible format.
>
> When upgrading a stable distribution, please use configure option --with-default-luks-format=LUKS1 to maintain backward compatibility.

You can check if LUKS2 is the default for your flavor of cryptsetup:

```
$ cryptsetup --help
[...]
Default compiled-in metadata format is LUKS2 (for luksFormat action).

Default PBKDF for LUKS2: argon2i
    Iteration time: 2000, Memory required: 1048576kB, Parallel threads: 4
```

In general, there is no strong reason to avoid LUKS2, as long as you are aware of the caveats (such as GRUB compatibility or excessive RAM usage in the luksOpen phase).

If you want to stick with LUKS1 for any reason, just specify it:

```
# cryptsetup luksFormat --type luks1 /dev/sdx9
```